# Can the story-identification tag be used for questions asking for movie identification?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I had asked a movie identification question on the Movies.SE site, but quickly I was told that the tag isn't on-topic there anymore.

Can I use the story-identification tag on this site, Science Fiction & Fantasy, to ask a movie identification question?

Comment: With the proviso that it's **a science fiction or fantasy film**, of course...

Comment: Read the tag wiki maybe? _"Use for identifying a work of SF or Fantasy, including novels, **movies**, comic books, fanfic, TV series, [...]_"

Answer (score 6):

[Yes.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification+movie) Identifying sci-fi or fantasy movies is as on-topic here as identifying sci-fi or fantasy anything else.